# Consuming wcfRest service from android/iphone

Tags: iphone, android, wcf, wcf-client

I need some good suggestions and ideas.

I have wcfRest service and the client is iPhone and Android. The client will GET and POST data.

I also made an API key which is a GUID, for the client.

BUT, do the client need to supply the api key with every method they request?? Or is there any way that I can store in the session or something??

for example:

json/getUserDetails/{userID}/{apikey}

json/saveUser/{apikey}

Comment: add apikey to Header ... anyway `json/saveUser` `json/getUserDetails` don't look like real REST service ... should be json/User for both get and save but with different HTTP methods ...

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try and will get back.

Comment: Hi, I sent the apikey to the header. But how to read that in my wcf?? I am stuck in there..:(

Comment: OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders

Comment: Hi. Thanks. what i am trying to do is int index = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.FindHeader("apikey", "ns"); what is this "ns"??

Comment: my bad ... it's for custom xml headers ... http://kennyw.com/work/indigo/153 and use httpRequestProperty.Headers

Comment: if (WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers["apikey"] == null){return "no header";}
else{//do the work here}---this is working good for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to send ***something*** on each request - whether it's the API key or an authenticated header, you need a way to authenticate the caller.  So the easiest way would be to send the api key with each request, although using the header is a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

You could try checking out OAuth, that's the security method Twitter, Facebook, Google and others use. Since sending the API key to the server could lead you to someone getting it and doing stuff you might not like.

**OAuth**

An open protocol to allow secure API authorization in a simple and standard method from desktop and web applications. It also works with mobile.

http://oauth.net/

Also check out the different languages http://oauth.net/code/